# how to get the value to td inside list in javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net

I have a listview in asp.net it appears in html like this

```
<li id="l3" class="add" onclick="hilite()" style="">
   <table id="tbl" style="width: 100%;">
       <tbody>
          <tr style="width: 100%;">
              <td class="border2" style="width: 50%;"> 1011 </td>
              <td class="border2" style="width: 50%;"> Name 3 </td>
           </tr>
       </tbody>
    </table>
</li>
```

now i want to get all the table value via javascript on button click  li contains table inside table tr and td presented i want td value of each list for sorting. 
and also i tried like this

```
function sortUnorderedList(ul, sortDescending) {
        if (typeof ul == "string")
            ul = document.getElementById(ul);
        var lis = ul.getElementsByTagName("li");
        var vals = [];
        for (var i = 0, l = lis.length; i < l; i++)
            vals.push(lis[i].innerHTML);
        vals.sort();
        if (sortDescending)
            vals.reverse();

        var contentArray = new Array();
        for (var i = 0, l = lis.length; i < l; i++) {
            lis[i].innerHTML = vals[i];

            alert(lis[i].innerHTML);

            var x = lis[i].innerHTML.getElementById('lsttable1').rows[0].cells;
            alert(x[0].innerHTML);
        }
 }
```

in `alert(x[0].innerHTML);` i got table then how should i take the td value of each li

Comment: Are you using jquery? I see the tag but no reference to it in your code sample.

Answer (score 4):

This will display the value of each td in your list, using jquery.

```
$("ul li.add table td").each(function(){
   alert($(this).html());
});
```

If you need a specific list, you can use the id selector. To get the first row in the table, use the tr:first selector.

```
$("#l3 li.add table tr:first td").each(function(){
   alert($(this).html());
});
```

Take a look at the [selector documentation](http://api.jquery.com/category/selectors/) for more.

Comment: You only showed one `ListView`. Please update your question with additional `ListView` markup if you need help with them as well.

Comment: the above code is taking value of all li in the page, i want to take first column of table inside particular list by id wise.